# Is there a method to get hStdOutput into an string buffer?

Tags: c++, winapi, file-io, console-application, c++20

I've successfully made an handle that gets the output from an external program and then exports out to a file. I want to do this with an `stringstream` or equivalent instead. Here's a code snippet to show what I want to do

```
//std::string OUTPATH = _FilePath + L"out";
std::string filestream{};

//HANDLE h = CreateFileA(LuaBuffer.data(),
//    FILE_APPEND_DATA,
//    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
//    &sa,
//    CREATE_ALWAYS,
//    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
//    NULL);

si.hStdOutput = filestream.data();
si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
```

If this is impossible, then what is the fastest approach to getting an output from an external console program? Many thanks.

Comment: `si.hStdOutput = h` must be. h must be inherited, process created with inherited handles and use UpdateProcThreadAttribute for h

Comment: @RbMm that will write the output directly to a file. The OP want to write the output to a memory buffer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `std::string/stream` with the `STARTUPINFO::hStdOut` field. What you CAN do is create a pipe via `CreatePipe()` instead, and then your app can read from the pipe and append the data to your `std::string/stream`.

See MSDN's documentation for an example of using `CreatePipe()` with `CreateProcess()` to capture a child process's output.

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output)

Simply change the code to write the captured output to your `std::string/stream` instead of to the parent process's `stdout`.